# How many lights did Gul Madred show to Picard?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard, 1984

I have seen a few people discussing this, and I was wondering if anyone thought it was possible that in the Star Trek: The Next Generation episode, Chain of Command, the Cardassian interrogator Gul Madred had actually brought in a fifth light and that is why Picard said he saw five at the end of the episode? When Madred asks Picard for the last time, we can't see how many lights there actually are. I know the whole thing is supposed to be a reference to "1984" but TNG was clearly doing its own thing.

Comment: There are four lights!

Comment: I know that there were four lights throughout the episode, But when the Cardassian asks Picard for the very last time, we cannot see the lights. Later when Picard is discussing his ordeal with Troi, he says at that point he would have said anything, but he genuinely did believe he saw five lights. I was simply proposing the idea that perhaps the Cardassian  had brought in a fifth light, just to mess with Picard. The only alternative is that Picard is now insane.

Comment: There's no evidence that the Cardassian brought in a fifth light.  Given the nature of the episode and the point it was making about a person (Picard) being pushed to their limits via torture (not physical in this case, but mental,) I think the idea was that Picard was so ready to say there were 5 lights that his mind was beginning to convince him there WERE 5 lights.  Call that (temporary) insanity if you like, but he obviously got over it.

Comment: five, of course! Are you suggesting otherwise?